# Changing the Key Modifiers (CMD<->CTRL) affects VM

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I changed my <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd> to behave like <kbd>⌃CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>⌃CTRL</kbd> to behave like a <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>, but this affects also my VirtualBox VM.

So I do <kbd>⌃CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for Copy in Mac, but I gotta do <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy in Ubuntu...

That's pretty confusing, is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 1):

I saw that VMWare has this possibility, VirtualBox not.

I know use a headless VM (No GUI) so I use the OSX Terminal for all operations, behavior stays the same.